# Hibernate criteria builder function did not match expected type

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I'm implementing an API that needs to support variable precision date / datetime matching.

My postgres database has a `created_at` column of type `timestamptz` which correlates to a property in the entity of type `ZonedDateTime`.

I am trying to use the following criteria query predicate to filter these timestamps (a hardcoded example for ease of debugging)

I am looking to generate an SQL query similar to

```sql
select * from my_table where date_trunc('day', created_at) = '1992-10-19';
```

with

```java
criteriaBuilder.equal(
                                criteriaBuilder.function("date_trunc", String.class, criteriaBuilder.literal("day"), root.get(MyEntity_.CREATED_AT)),
                                criteriaBuilder.literal("1992-10-19")
                        )
```

However when this code is run it yields the following exception

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1992-10-19] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:501) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler$1$1.bind(CriteriaCompiler.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl$1.buildCompiledQuery(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:364) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaCompiler.compile(CriteriaCompiler.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:774) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.8.Final.jar!/:5.6.8.Final]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
```

I'm not sure where the hibernate param validator is getting the date type from given I'm telling the function the return type is `String.class`

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do with a criteria query?